# How to uninstall a default plugin in RAD

Tags: eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse, uninstallation

I have seen many posts about here which tell you how to uninstall a plug-in that YOU have installed. What I want to know is - How do you uninstall a plug-in that comes along with the eclipse package? I tried the installation manager but it doesnt work since this like a default plugin.
I am using IBM Rational Developers for System Z with Java version 8.3. I am trying to install GEF Zest Visualisation but since GEF Draw2D was already pre-installed in my RDZ i am not able to install what I want due to conflicting dependency. 
I need GEF Zest Visualisation so that I can install Maven. Without Zest I get an error while I try installing Maven.
Is there a way to uninstall these default plug-ins? If no, then is there any workaround that I can use to install my Maven plug-in without having to use Zest?

Comment: FYI: I cannot delete the plugins from the folder system because I am using a client machine and I dont have the required access to delete files from the said folder.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Rational Developer for System Z, but if it is Eclipse-based it should be the same as Rational Application Developer or Eclipse.

1. Open **Help** context menu.
2. Press **About Rational Developer...**
3. Click the **Installation Details** button.
4. This will open a list of installed software and you can see all the features and plug-ins that are installed.
5. Find and select the item you want to uninstall.
6. Click the **Uninstall...** button.

This will attempt to uninstall the selected plug-in, but you will likely encounter dependency issues if Maven requires GEF Zest Visualisation. You would need to uninstall Maven first if that happens.